# App crashes on iOS 8.4

Tags: ios, swift, crash

The app runs perfect on iOS 9.3 however when I try to run it on iOS 8.4 it crashes. It seems like it's crashing on the stuff I've linked up interface builder. Everything however is referenced to and since its runs fine on iOS 9.3 I know nothing is nil.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

we weren't loading the ViewControllers correctly. We were doing this:

```
mainViewController = TabViewController()
```

That works perfectly on iOS9 but on iOS8 one has to do this:

```
mainViewController = TabViewController(nibName: "TabView", bundle: nil)
```

Answer (score 0):

replace `!` with `?` in your `outlets` because you are changing it's different properties so it should be `optional`.

for example,

```
  @IBOutlet weak var signupButton: UIButton?
  //make every outlet optional which you will change in future
```

hope this will help :)